# mapbox.js 1.6.2 - change tileset on zoom level

Tags: javascript, zooming, tiles, mapbox

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'wmarci.i6n42nl5',

{
    center: new L.LatLng(38.8929,-100.0252),
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 18,
    layers: [
        L.tileLayer('wmarci.k300ifal', {
        maxZoom: 13,
        minZoom: 5,
    })
    ]
});

This doesn't seem to be working.... ideas? Am I calling the tilelayer wrong?

Comment: try ```L.mapbox.tileLayer```

Comment: @AlexFilatov that worked, I saw the tile set for split second, but now I think the basemap is screwing it up...
        var layers = [{
              name: 'basemap',
              layer: L.layerGroup([
               L.mapbox.tileLayer('wmarci.i6n42nl5'),
               L.mapbox.gridLayer('')])
          }

Answer (score 0):

something like this, use a tileLayer (defined earlier) and turn it off and on based on zoom level...

```
map.on('zoomend load ready', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 16) {
        map.removeLayer(zoomedinmap);
    } else {
        map.addLayer(zoomedinmap);
    }
});
```